# An error occurred while calling o590.save. : java.lang.RuntimeException: quote cannot be more than one character

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

When I use pyspark to write to the csv file:

```
sql_df.write\
    .format("csv")\
    .option('sep', '\t')\
    .option("compression", "gzip")\
    .option("quote", "\u0000")\
    .option('ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace', 'false')\
    .option('ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace', 'false')\
    .mode('append')\
    .option('nullValue', None)\
        .save(output)
```

a problem occurs:

```
File "/home/disk2/task_data/work/20220427/0.am.yarn_appattempt_1648102470091_228601_000001--M4505-C4-P0/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o590.save.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: quote cannot be more than one character
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVOptions.getChar(CSVOptions.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVOptions.<init>(CSVOptions.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVOptions.<init>(CSVOptions.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat.prepareWrite(CSVFileFormat.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:168)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:229)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's just like the error says it's not [accepting your unicode as a single character](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/a92ef00145b264013e11de12f2c7cee62c28198d/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/csv/CSVOptions.scala).  use "" instead for null value.